# Accidently admob live ad was displayed, should i be worried?

Tags: android, admob

I was doing testing of my admob apps, and I forgot to add test device code in a particular activity, and Live ad was displayed on the device. I didn't clicked it though, should i be worried? will i lose my account?

Comment: they will close your account for some weeks if you click it many times. I know it because I did it :-)

Comment: Do not worry since your device in debug mode it is unncessary to put test device code. You can check logs to be sure :)

Comment: @StefanBeike Yes same happened to me long before, and this time i was so careful and then i forgot to add in one activity :( I didnt clicked it , it just got displayed.

Comment: @adnbsr Is it? but in their document they have specified that "Using live ads during development is against AdMob policy; if you test on live ads, your AdMob account may be suspended." What about this?

Comment: Yep. They say "may" it depends how much you break the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be worried, google was well aware of these type of accidents. If you kept using it on developer mode, will result in a problem of terminating your admob account. Not this type of accidents.

Been in the same situation. Nothing happened.

Comment: "If you kept using it on developer mode" means? I was in developer mode when its displayed.

Comment: If you kept showing it on developer mode, after the app is published on playstore  not an issue. if you are doing the same before publishing. there is a big chance that your account is blocked by admob.

Comment: I am developing only, Version without admob is in playstore, I Flashed my device last week and it changed its device device ID, I updated the new device ID in all activity except one, and when i was testing Live Ad was displayed :( I didnt clicked though..but impression was made.

Comment: it's fine. don't repeat it.